# How to make PouchDB work offline?

Tags: pouchdb, offlineapps

I am not an advanced web developer which is why I feel like I am asking a stupid question, but I couldn't find any instructions of how to make a pouchDB website working offline. The fact that I didn't find anything probably means it is pretty straight forward but somehow my website is not loading once internet connection is not available.

At the beginning of my code I am creating the PouchDB databases like this:

```
data = new PouchDB('data');
users = new PouchDB('local_users');
templates = new PouchDB('templates');
```

After that I am syncing the databases with my CouchDB databases:

```
//Set remote databases
var remoteCouchDA = new PouchDB('myCouchDB_URL/data');
var remoteCouchTE = new PouchDB('myCouchDB_URL/templates');
var remoteCouchUS = new PouchDB('myCouchDB_URL/usersdoc', {skipSetup: true});


// Initialise a sync with the remote server
function syncDA() {
  var opts = {live: true, retry: true};
  data.sync(remoteCouchDA, opts);
};

function syncTE() {
    var opts = {live: true, retry: true};
    templates.sync(remoteCouchTE, opts);
};
function syncUS() {
      var opts = {live: true, retry: true};
      users.sync(remoteCouchUS, opts);
    };

if (remoteCouchDA) {
    syncDA();
    }

if (remoteCouchTE) {
    syncTE();
    }

if (remoteCouchUS) {
    syncUS();
    }
```

The documents I get with `localDB.allDocs()`. It would be really great if someone could tell me what else I need to do to make the website work offline.

Answer (score 2):

PouchDB will take care of storing your data locally, so that is available offline, but to allow also your website to still load when offline you have to make sure that your assets (html, javascript and css files) are cached locally too. For that you can use the [Service Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API).

Service Worker is quite powerful and can be a bit daunting at first but there are libraries that can help you with the setup, like [UpUp](https://www.talater.com/upup/) or for more complex use cases [Service Worker Precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache).

Comment: Thanks, Patricia. I was a little bit short-minded with that, but this makes perfectly sense ^^